# Creat a inverse distance weighting Function in VBA

Tags: python, vba

I want to estimate the inverse distance weighting (IDW) interpolation value of rainfall.
I identified the nearest three stations to the needed station to obtain the interpolated value.

I have the following table:

[image]

So, the equation of IDW:

```
[(Station_valu1/Dist1^2)+(Station_valu2/Dist2^2)+(Station_valu3/Dist3^2)]
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
1/Dist1^2 + 1/Dist2^2 + 1/Dist3^2
```

There would be several situations trying to address them in this equation:

1) If `Value1` or `Dist1` are empty and `Value2`, `Dist2`, `Value3`, `Dist3` are not

then, disregard `Value1`, `Dist1` from the equation, and consider only  `Value2`, `Dist2`, and `Value3`, `Dist3`.

Result of IDW will be:

```
[Station_valu2/Dist2^2)+(Station_valu3/Dist3^2)] 
————————————————————————————————————————————————
Dist2^2 + 1/Dist3^2
```

We will have the same scenario with `Value2`, `Dist2`, and `Value3`, `Dist3` if anyone of them has null value.

I came up with this code:

```
Function IDWW(Value1, Value2, Value3, Dist1,Dist2,Dist3)
Dim a1 As Variant
Dim b1 As Variant

Dim a2 As Variant
Dim b2 As Variant

Dim a3 As Variant
Dim b3 As Variant





    If Value1 <> "" And Dist1 <> "" Then
        a1 = Value1 / (Dist1) ^ 2
        b1 = 1 / (Dist1) ^ 2

        ElseIF Value1 = "" OR Dist1 = "" Then
        a1 = ""
        b1 = ""

    End If


    If Value2 <> "" And Dist2 <> "" Then
        a2 = Value2 / (Dist2) ^ 2
        b2 = 1 / (Dist2) ^ 2

        ElseIF Value1 = "" OR Dist1 = "" Then
        a2 = ""
        b2 = ""

    End If


    If Value3 <> "" And Dist3 <> "" Then
        a3 = Value3 / (Dist3) ^ 2
        b3 = 1 / (Dist3) ^ 2

        ElseIF Value3 = "" OR Dist3 = "" Then
        a3 = ""
        b3 = ""

    End If




    IDWW = (a1+a2+a3) / (b1+b2+b3)



End Function
```

Please, I need your help to solve this issue!

Comment: Don't set your variables to be `""` - set them to be `0` instead.  (i.e. change `a1 = ""` etc to be `a1 = 0`)   And then avoid a potential division by zero at the end by checking that `(b1+b2+b3)` isn't equal to zero before doing the division.

Comment: I did before and still having #value in IDW cell

Comment: Did you get the `#VALUE` error even when you checked for `b1+b2+b3` being 0?  Or did you set the values to `0` but didn't have a test for division by zero if they were all zero?  (To be honest, a `#VALUE` is probably the appropriate response if the three distances are all missing.)

Comment: (a) I assume the "Empty" in your image of your sheet was just put there to indicate the cell was empty.  Or is the actual word "Empty" in your cells?  (b) How does the [python] tag relate to this question?  This seems to be a straight Excel UDF.

Comment: I tried to make a and b to equal to zero, I get error even when I fill all value1,dist1...dist3 with value. I worked a lot on that and always error!

Comment: I just added Empty word to explain to you guys. But in real data, there is not empty word! Sorry this is is VBA excel, I should mentioned from the began, but I had to add Python in tags in order to post my question

Comment: Your existing code works for me for the first line of data in your image (i.e. when there is nothing being set to `""`).  I used a formula in cell H2 in the worksheet of `=idww(A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2)`.

Comment: "but I had to add Python in tags in order to post my question" - that sounds like a bug and should be posted on meta.  No tag is compulsory.  All you need is one tag of any sort, so [vba] by itself should have been accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, all you want to do is set values to be zero if they are empty:

```vb
Function IDWW(Value1, Value2, Value3, Dist1,Dist2,Dist3)
    Dim a1 As Variant
    Dim b1 As Variant
    Dim a2 As Variant
    Dim b2 As Variant
    Dim a3 As Variant
    Dim b3 As Variant

    If Value1 <> "" And Dist1 <> "" Then
        a1 = Value1 / (Dist1) ^ 2
        b1 = 1 / (Dist1) ^ 2
    Else
        a1 = 0
        b1 = 0
    End If

    If Value2 <> "" And Dist2 <> "" Then
        a2 = Value2 / (Dist2) ^ 2
        b2 = 1 / (Dist2) ^ 2
    Else
        a2 = 0
        b2 = 0
    End If

    If Value3 <> "" And Dist3 <> "" Then
        a3 = Value3 / (Dist3) ^ 2
        b3 = 1 / (Dist3) ^ 2
    Else
        a3 = 0
        b3 = 0
    End If

    'Avoid a problem if all 3 distances are empty
    If b1 + b2 + b3 = 0 Then
        IDWW = 0
    Else
        IDWW = (a1+a2+a3) / (b1+b2+b3)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Ok great, I will try that now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks man, it works perfectly. I will keep you updated if there is a new problem with it :)